# Regex multiple lookbehinds order

Tags: regex

I've got a regex that I want to use to match word characters after a `-` if there are not any proceeding word characters.

```
(?<!\w)(?<=-)\w+
```

For the string

```
I want -to match a word-if it has a '-' bofore it and only-if '-' is not preceded by a word character.
```

I would expect it to only match `to`. However, it actually matches `to`, `if`, and `if`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4DeC6d/1/)

If I take the positive lookbehind out

```
(?<!\w)-\w+
```

In the same string, it only matches `-to` as expected but I don't want the `-` in the match information.

Is it possible to chain positive and negative lookbehinds so they happen in order?

Comment: Maybe just use `\W-(\w+)` and fetch group one? And `(?:\W|^)-(\w+)` would also match at the start of a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern that you tried `(?<!\w)(?<=-)\w+` makes 2 assertions the current position:

- `(?<!\w)` is there not a word character directly to the left
- `(?<=-)` is there a - directly to the left

This can also be written as just `(?<=-)\w+` as the positive lookbehind asserts that the exact match should be at the left.

You get the matches `to`, `if`, and `if` because that assertion is true at multiple places.

---

You can use `(?<=\W-)` to assert what is directly to the left is a non word character `\W` followed by `-`

```
(?<=\W-)\w+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LeAN6g/1)

Comment: Thanks for this and it seems to work well. Is there any way to get it to match word characters if they were at the start `-I want -to match a word-if it has a '-' bofore it and only-if '-' is not preceded by a word character.` where both `I` and `to` would match. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LeAN6g/3)

Comment: @Dan One option is then to use 2 `(?:(?<=\W-)|(?<=^-))\w+`  lookbehinds https://regex101.com/r/DF22Pt/1

Comment: Thanks again for all the help

Comment: @Dan Some engines also support `(?<=(?:\W|^)-)\w+` See https://regex101.com/r/SiiBcF/1

Answer (score 1):

Use

```php
(?<=\B-)\w+
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/VypPbS/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \B                       the boundary between two word chars (\w)
                             or two non-word chars (\W)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Going to leave the other one ticked but both work :)